# Mirror ViewController to External Display

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to in code, get my view on the iPad app to mirror to an External Display.  In AppDelegate didFinishLaunching, I have:

```
 if ([[UIScreen screens] count] > 1)
    {
        UIScreen *secondScreen = [[UIScreen screens] objectAtIndex:1];
        NSString *availableModeString;

        for (int i = 0; i < secondScreen.availableModes.count; i++)
        {
            availableModeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f, %f",
                                   ((UIScreenMode *)[secondScreen.availableModes objectAtIndex:i]).size.width,
                                   ((UIScreenMode *)[secondScreen.availableModes objectAtIndex:i]).size.height];

            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Available Mode" message:availableModeString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
            availableModeString = nil;
        }

        // undocumented value 3 means no overscan compensation
        secondScreen.overscanCompensation = 3;

        self.secondWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1280, 720)];
        self.secondWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        self.secondWindow.screen = secondScreen;

        ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
        self.secondWindow.rootViewController = viewController;

        self.secondWindow.hidden = NO;
    }
```

All that shows up in the external display is the blue background color set in code.

Comment: Are you talking about providing a live feed using video or just mimicing the view on the second screen?

More importantly, are we letting the second screen change the first screen using touches or not?

Comment: Mostly just mirroring what is on the iPad screen to the Apple TV, ?75 doing so in HD...without the 4 bars around the screen which is what happens when you simply do AirPlay mirroring from command center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can mirror a view on my iPhone 6 using this:

```
@interface MirrorViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *viewToMirror;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *snapshotView;

@end

@implementation MirrorViewController

- (instancetype)initWithViewToMirror:(UIView*)view
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    if (self == nil) return nil;
    self.viewToMirror = view;
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    CADisplayLink *displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(update)];
    [displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}

- (void)update
{
    [self.snapshotView removeFromSuperview];
    self.snapshotView = [self.viewToMirror snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:self.snapshotView];
}

@end
```

Here's how you could use it in your didFinishLaunching code:

```
if ([[UIScreen screens] count] > 1)
{
    UIScreen *secondScreen = [[UIScreen screens] objectAtIndex:1];

    // [...]

    self.secondWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1280, 720)];
    self.secondWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    self.secondWindow.screen = secondScreen;

    MirrorViewController *mirrorViewController = [[MirrorViewController alloc] initWithViewToMirror:self.window.rootViewController.view];
    self.secondWindow.rootViewController = mirrorViewController;

    self.secondWindow.hidden = NO;
}
```

I haven't tested it on an iPad with external display though because i don't have the gear.

Comment: Um....I'm not sure where this is supposed to go, or how it is supposed to be called?  Is that supposed to be didLoadView?

Comment: `loadView` is called automatically by UIKit when a UIViewController's view needs to be loaded. You implement a UIViewController subclass and override loadView like my example code. I haven't tested if using snabshotView to mirror a view like this works but if it does, that code should be all you need :)

Comment: Also, i changed the code a bit since i first posted it

Comment: Do you know how to update this code to iOS 13? The `screen` setter is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

First checks for the presence of an external display at app startup. If a second display is available, it creates a window for it. I used following code in my app.

```
(void)checkForExistingScreenAndInitializeIfPresent
{
    if ([[UIScreen screens] count] > 1)
    {
        // Get the screen object that represents the external display.
        UIScreen *secondScreen = [[UIScreen screens] objectAtIndex:1];
        // Get the screen's bounds so that you can create a window of the correct size.
        CGRect screenBounds = secondScreen.bounds;

        self.secondWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds];
        self.secondWindow.screen = secondScreen;

        // Set up initial content to display...
        // Show the window.
        self.secondWindow.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

Thien register for connection and disconnection notifications by following code.

```
(void)setUpScreenConnectionNotificationHandlers
{
    NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

    [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleScreenDidConnectNotification:)
            name:UIScreenDidConnectNotification object:nil];
    [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleScreenDidDisconnectNotification:)
            name:UIScreenDidDisconnectNotification object:nil];
}
```

Handling screen connection and disconnection notifications

```
(void)handleScreenDidConnectNotification:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    UIScreen *newScreen = [aNotification object];
    CGRect screenBounds = newScreen.bounds;

    if (!self.secondWindow)
    {
        self.secondWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds];
        self.secondWindow.screen = newScreen;

        // Set the initial UI for the window.
    }
}

(void)handleScreenDidDisconnectNotification:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    if (self.secondWindow)
    {
        // Hide and then delete the window.
        self.secondWindow.hidden = YES;
        self.secondWindow = nil;

    }

}
```

If you don’t create a window for the display—or if you create a window but don’t show it—a black field is displayed on the external display.

**There’s no guarantee that all modes will be available in an external display, so you should not depend on the availability of a specific mode.**

In rare cases, you might want to use a different value for the `overscanCompensation` property, but doing so always results in more work that you have to do. For example, if you use `UIScreenOverscanCompensationInsetBounds`, you must be prepared to handle the bounds of nonstandard display sizes.